# Is it OK to reuse variables in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, variables, memory

Please notice how the `Category` variable is used in both methods below.  I would think that Method 1 would not be good because a new instance of the variable is created with every loop, so why do I see so many codes examples that use this strategy? I would think Method 2 would be better because it would use less memory.

Method 1

```
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];  
json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

for (int i=0; i < json.count; i++)
{
    NSString * Category = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"CategoryID"]; 

    //do something here
}
```

---

Method 2

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];  
json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

NSString * Category 
for (int i=0; i < json.count; i++)
{
    Category = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"CategoryID"];

    //do something here
}
```

Comment: Keep your code as clear as possible and let the compiler worry about optimization, unless profiling has shown you that there is an issue.

Comment: Ignoring ARC, they both use the same amount of memory.  And it costs nothing to "create" a local variable.  In general, one should keep the scope of variables as small as possible (easier to understand and fewer bugs), and that goes double for ARC.

Answer (score 3):

The two methods are functionally identical. All you're doing in the second one is giving the variable a wider scope (in the first version the scope is limited to the loop).

For this reason you should prefer the first version, since scope should be limited as far as possible.

A new value is still created each time. You're confusing variable declaration with variable assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example is the better way. Creating a variable declaration has no cost. The compiler will optimize it away if it's not needed. Reusing variables is a common source of bugs and should generally be avoided.

Reusing *objects* is a completely different thing, and sometimes is very important for performance. But `Category` is not an object, it's just a pointer to an object. (Note that variables should always have leading lowercase. Leading uppercase indicates that it's a class.)

Even so, this still is not the best way. You should avoid `objectAtIndex:` when you can, and instead use enumeration. This is safer, clearer, *and* more efficient.

```
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];  
NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
// You really should validate that json is an array and check for errors. 

for (NSString *category in [json valueForKey:@"CategoryID"])
{
    //do something here
}
```

This works by using the KVC method `[NSArray valueForKey:]`, which returns a new array of the given properties. That said, you need to be very careful with this if you're pulling from an external source. If you get malformed data, you're going to crash. You need to make sure that you get what you expected.

Answer (score 1):

Local variables are created on the stack. When you enter the scope, the stack pointer gets moved to make room for the variable. Then when you leave the scope the space for that variable gets popped off the top of the stack.

When you're talking about a variable that is a pointer to an object, we are talking about either 4 or 8 bytes (4 for a 32 bit device, 8 for a 64 bit device.) A trivial amount of memory.

In your first example, the stack pointer gets moved to make room for the `Category` variable (should be lower case, `category` to follow Cocoa naming conventions btw) at the beginning of the `for` loop, and then the memory is discarded once the loop finishes executing. The memory is never wasted, just used temporarily.

It is not correct to say that "...a new instance of the variable is created with every loop". The variable is created before entering the loop and discarded afterwords.

In your second example, the variable is defined at the scope of the method. Thus the 4 (or 8) bytes stick around until the method completes. Once the method completes, though, the memory is recovered anyway.

Unless you have a stack overflow, local variables are not a meaningful consumer of memory. iOS device have hundreds of megabytes of memory, perhaps gigabytes. That's hundreds of millions of bytes, or even billions of bytes. Worrying about a single pointer local variable is like Bill Gates worrying about pocket change. I read once that somebody calculated that when Gates was CEO of Microsoft, if he saw a $100 bill on the street, it would not be a cost-effective use of his time to spend a few seconds bending over to pick it up. He'd make more money spending a few more seconds doing his job. Worrying about the space for a pointer variable is like Gates worrying about having one less one dollar bill (a dollar bill that he'll get back a fraction of a second later!)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond.  I like the Gates analogy.

Comment: No problem. And I promise I didn't kill your father! (Princess Bride reference)